# Algorithm to compare similarity of directed paths through directed graph

Tags: path, compare, similarity, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

I have a directed graph with two directed paths in it.

I want an algorithm to determine the similarity between the two paths.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632711/path-similarity-in-a-directed-graph) mentions using the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to determine an approximate similarity. I also realize that the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) uses a similar metric.

My question is:

How do you handle the case where two paths run parallel to each other. That is if the two paths have no similar nodes, yet would be considered 'similar' because their paths travel in the same direction very close to each other.

Thanks

Comment: You can come up with any metric you want. For instance, compute the distance between the 1st nodes in each path, between the second nodes, etc. and do something like 1/(1+d1+d2+...+dn), and then multiply by x=0.9^|length1 - length2| or something.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple answer is that this is a very hard question, and relies a lot on your definition of what 'similar' means in a graph. In most graphs you could rearrange the nodes of two disjoint paths in a planar fashion so as to appear to run 'parallel'.

A good place to start looking at more advanced similarity metrics would be to consider the graph's adjacency matrix, and look at various [matrix similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similar_matrix) algorithms.

Edit: Restricting the question to Euclidian graphs

There's plenty of active research on this question when restricting the domain to Euclidian graphs, as this is an applicable topic to areas like GIS, machine learning applications to robotics, and collaborative filtering on social networks / artificial networks like the web. Check out the articles on [google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=euclidean+graph+similarity&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart).

Comment: You can't rearrange the nodes in my graph, as each node represents a physical location on a map. It does sound like I've chosen a question which is rather difficult. I was just wondering if there are any specific algorithms which might have already been made which I didn't know about.

Comment: Ah, then you're talking about a very specific restriction of graph theory, called Euclidian graphs. See edited post.

Comment: i think what he described is more of a geometrical graph than an Euclidean graph. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_graph_theory and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EuclideanGraph.html